# Using appsettings.json in C# selenium automation project

Tags: c#, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I'm working on automation tests which I'm still new to writing the scripts.
I'll try to be as short as possible. **I'm building everything in .NET CORE. Selenium C# in Visual Studio**

Basically what I would like to know is how to pull string from appsettings.json file to my test class file?

Basically what I have inside my **appsettings.json file** ->

```
  "BaseURL": "https://google.com/",
```

What I have in my test clase is:

```
    
       [TestCase]
        public void LoginToGmail()
        
            *currently Im using hardcoded version of*
            driver.url = "https://google.com/"*
            IWebElement GmailLogo = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath.......);
            Assert.IsTrue(GmailLogo.Displayed);
```

```
But I would like to use something like driver.url = "BaseURL" <- (string from the .json file)
```

How do you pull it from the .json file?

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class to read the config file. Assuming this structure for appsettings.json:

```json
{
    "BaseURL": "https://..."
}
```

Reading and using the configuration becomes:

```cs
var settings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

driver.Url = settings["BaseURL"];
```

**Important:** Be sure the "Copy to Output Directory" property on appsettings.json is set to "Always" or "If Newer" (right-click on appsettings.json in Solution Explorer and choose "Properties"):

[image: Screenshot of properties pane for appsettings.json]

Comment: I was hard coding my urls as well until I saw this post.  Is there a way to set it up to run based on  different environments?  Right now I have my base url set to https://localhost:5001.

Answer (score 1):

Any JSON can be deserialised into a class using C#, this is not limited to an appsettings.json file and you may find it useful to store data sets in json format for testing purposes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @SteveBeck for the link, helped me. Also thanks to @Greg Burghardt.
I managed to set it up like this: created new class for the read Json file and browser startup/close.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class NewSetup
{

    public class GetSetUpFile
    {
        public string BaseURL { get; set; }
        public string SetupJson { get; set; }
        private readonly string _strSetupFile;

        public GetSetUpFile(string jsonfile)
        {
            _strSetupFile = jsonfile;
        }

        public void ReadSetUpFile()
        {

            SetupJson = File.ReadAllText(_strSetupFile);
        }

        public class StartBrowserDriver
        {

             protected IWebDriver driver;

            [SetUp]
            public void StartBrowser()
            {
                var setup = new GetSetUpFile(@"C:\\PATH\\\TO\\\appsettings.json");
                setup.ReadSetUpFile();
                //Deserialize json objects
                setup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetSetUpFile>(setup.SetupJson);
                var url = setup.BaseURL;
                var DesiredURL = url;
                driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Driver");
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(DesiredURL);
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            }
            [TearDown]
            public void CloseBrowser()
            {
                driver.Close();
                driver.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Navigate back to your main test class:

```
  
class User_is_able_to_login_to_Gmail : StartAndCloseBrowserDriver
{
[TestCase]
public void public void LoginToGmail();
IWebElement GmailLogo = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath.......);
Assert.IsTrue(GmailLogo.Displayed);
GmailLogo.Click();
\\\\continue\\\\
```

The test runs & works.
If someone has some pointers about the build, please let me know :)
Thanks to everyone!